# How to convert BitmapFrame into BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf

My program uses some WPF APIs to process images in a folder.  I need to parse EXIF data from the images if there is any in order to get the value of the `DateTimeOriginal` property.  I've been using a `BitmapImage` to load the image from a `MemoryStream`, but I need a `BitmapFrame` object to get at the `BitmapMetadata` object.

Here's my original code before I was given the requirement to get the `DateTimeOriginal` EXIF property:

```
BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
try {
    using ( MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream( snapshot.ImageData ) ) {
        src.BeginInit();
        src.CacheOption  = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        src.StreamSource = memoryStream;
        src.EndInit();
    }
} catch ( NotSupportedException ex ) {
    . . .
}
```

Now, to get the `BitmapFrame`, I need to create a `BitmapDecoder` and use the `Frames[0]` property.  So I added the following right after the `using` statement:

```
BitmapDecoder decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create( memoryStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad );
```

This decodes the bitmap and gets the first Frame, which is cool.  I still need to create the `BitmapImage`.  I can do that by resetting the `MemoryStream's` position back to the beginning and keeping the code that's already there, but this will decode the same image a second time.

Is there a way I can convert the `BitmapFrame` into a `BitmapImage`?  I thought I would cast the `BitmapFrame` into a `BitmapSource`object and then set the `BitmapImage's Source` propert, but the `BitmapImage` class doesn't seem to have a `Source` property.

Is this possible?  If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be no need for this conversion. The Remarks section in the `BitmapImage` MSDN page says:

> BitmapImage primarily exists to support Extensible Application Markup
>   Language (XAML) syntax and introduces additional properties for bitmap
>   loading that are not defined by BitmapSource.

When using bitmaps, your application should usually always use the `BitmapSource` or `ImageSource` base classes. For example when you assign the `Source` property of the WPF Image control, you can use an instance of any type derived from `ImageSource`, because that is the type of the `Source` property.

So you could directly use a `BitmapFrame` because it also derives from `ImageSource`:

```
var bitmap = BitmapFrame.Create(
    memoryStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);

image.Source = bitmap;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I figured that out last night but I couldn't try it this morning.  You're absolutely right, the `BitmapFrame` is all that I need. I've removed the `BitmapImage` from the code and it works.